# Casting/Type Conversion Performance

Tags: c#, performance, casting

I have the following extension method

```
public static T Field<T>(this DataRow row, string columnName)
{
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(row[columnName], typeof(T));
}
```

It works, but I'm trying to speed it up.  Is there a way to speed that up?  With a case statement and then type specific conversions?  I've tried a few things like using int.Parse, but even though I know I want an int returned, I have to use ChangeType to get it to compile.

```
 return (T)Convert.ChangeType(intVal, typeof(T));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you actually need to perform a conversion, or are you just casting?

If you just need a cast then a simple `return (T)row[columnName];` should do the trick.

(By the way, is using `Convert.ChangeType` really causing performance problems? This sounds like unnecessary micro-optimisation to me. Having said that, I'd probably prefer the plain cast for readability reasons, assuming that it meets your requirements.)

Comment: @Luke, plain cast doesn't always work, whereas Convert.ChangeType seems to always be returning the correct value no matter the type I throw at it.

Comment: @Chad: Can you give some examples of where casting doesn't work but `ChangeType` does? eg, What's the underlying type/value of the column and what type are you trying to convert it to?

Comment: the underlying types vary, but they should always be convertible to one of the following: string, int, bool, DateTime, byte, float, decimal.

Comment: @Chad: Understood. In that case I'd stick with `ChangeType`. Is it really creating any performance problems?

Comment: it looked like it, but I don't think the performance analyzer is showing me everything...